# Using Regex Replace when looking for un-escaped characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've got a requirement that is basically this. If I have a string of text such as

```
"There once was an 'ugly' duckling but it could 
never have been \'Scarlett\' Johansen"
```

then I'd like to match the quotes that haven't already been escaped. These would be the ones around 'ugly' not the ones around 'Scarlett'.

I've spent quite a while on this using a little C# console app to test things and have come up with the following solution.

```
private static void RegexFunAndGames() {

  string result;
  string sampleText = @"Mr. Grant and Ms. Kelly  starred in the film \'To Catch A Thief' but not in 'Stardust' because they'd stopped acting by then";
  string rePattern = @"\\'";
  string replaceWith = "'";

  Console.WriteLine(sampleText);

  Regex regEx = new Regex(rePattern);
  result = regEx.Replace(sampleText, replaceWith);

  result = result.Replace("'", @"\'");

  Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Basically what I've done is a two step process find those characters that have already been escaped, undo that then do everything again. It sounds a bit clumsy and I feel that there could be a better way.

**Testing Information**

I got two really good answers so I thought it worth running a test to see which runs better. I have these two functions:

```
    private static string RegexReplace(string sampleText) {
        Regex regEx = new Regex("(?<!\\\\)'");
        return regEx.Replace(sampleText, "\\'");           
    }

    private static string ReplaceTest(string sampleText) {
        return sampleText.Replace(@"\'", "'").Replace("'", @"\'");
    }
```

And I call them in via the Main method in a console app:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        string sampleText = @"Mr. Grant and Ms. Kelly  starred in the film \'To Catch A Thief'  but not in 'Stardust' because they'd stopped acting by then.";
        string testReplace = string.Empty;
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 1000000; i > 0; i--) {
            testReplace = ReplaceTest(sampleText);
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("This method took '" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + "'");

        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 1000000; i > 0; i--) {
            testReplace = RegexReplace(sampleText);
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("This method took '" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + "'");
}
```

The method ReplaceTest takes 2068 milliseconds. The method RegexReplace takes 9372 milliseconds. I've ran this test a few times and ReplaceTest always comes out fastest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a *negative lookbehind* to make sure that the quote is *not* escaped: the expression below

```
(?<!\\)'
```

matches a single quote *unless* it is immediately preceded by a slash.

Note that slashes that go into string constants must be doubled.

```
var sampleText = @"Mr. Grant and Ms. Kelly  starred in the film \'To Catch A Thief' but not in 'Stardust' because they'd stopped acting by then";
var regEx = new Regex("(?<!\\\\)'");
var result = regEx.Replace(sampleText, "\\'");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The above prints

```
Mr. Grant and Ms. Kelly  starred in the film \'To Catch A Thief\' but not in \'Stardust\' because they\'d stopped acting by then
```

[Link to ideone.](http://ideone.com/SBycCd)

Comment: I'd started looking at 'negative lookbehind' but obviously hadn't looked hard enough. I'll wait and see if there are any other replies just in case but I'll probably mark this as my accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Is there an easy way to make sure this doesn't break if the slash before the quote is itself escaped with a slash?

Comment: @Rawling Sure - use `new Regex("(?<!(?<!\\\\)\\\\)'")` to say that the slash itself must not be preceded by a slash.

Comment: I'm marking this as my accepted answer since it works and answers my question. However, the answer by @NeverHopeless is equally as good.

Comment: @DanielHollinrake Note that fixing the second problem (i.e. *not* treating double-slashes as slashes in front of quotes) is easier with regex.

Comment: Hi. With my data there won't be double-slashes but thank you for mentioning that. Regex is more powerful and you can do more things with it. One reason why I wanted to learn more about them.

Answer (score 3):

I am surprised why you are using RegEx to do this why not simply use:

```
string result = sampleText.Replace(@"\'", "'").Replace("'", @"\'");
```

This will escape all the unescaped `'`.

It will first make all escaped `'`(single quote) unescaped, then will escape `all`.

Well, if `RegEx is the requirement`, you are going to accept the correct solution as you have already told.

Comment: The reason why I chose to use RegEx is that this seemed an ideal candidate for Regex. However, one reason for waiting before accepting an answer was to see what other people's opinions are. And good answers can always be voted up even after something's been marked as accepted. So it's 'never hopeless'!

Comment: I do like this answer. One of the problems I have with Regex is that I don't find them very readable. Your solution is much more human friendly.

Answer (score -1):

You could use

```
    string rePattern = @"[\\'|\']";
```

Instead

Comment: -1. `[\\'|\']` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches one character: a backslash, a pipe, or an apostrophe.